# WAMP site requests files from a different directory

Tags: php, wamp

I have a very strange behavior on my pc, using windows 7 and WAMP.

I have two sites:
ruth.local and ctf.dev.

Trying to browse ruth.local I get lots of errors like:  Notice: Undefined variable: db_name in C:\wamp\www\ctf.dev\settings\init.php on line 22

My httpd-vhosts.conf file has these entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@ctf.dev
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ctf.dev"
ServerName ctf.dev
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@ruth.local
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ruth.local"
ServerName ruth.local
ErrorLog "logs/ruth.local-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/ruth.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file has these:

```
127.0.0.1 ctf.dev
127.0.0.1 ruth.local
::1 ctf.dev
::1 ruth.local
```

Why does ruth.local tries to call files in ctf.dev?

Comment: This is likely to be more to do with the code than the VH definitions

Comment: Changing the order of declarations in the conf file helped. Still don't understand why.

Comment: Show us your `init.php`